Why do I have that black lines left, down and midst of my widget?
All my widgets are shifting slightly to the right and bottom, and my first two widgets also have a black space in the middle, why?
Headers:
#ifndef TOPAREACLASS_H
#define TOPAREACLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLineEdit>

class topAreaClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit topAreaClass(const QString& label,const QString& path, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QWidget* topArea;
    QWidget* leftTopArea;

    QHBoxLayout* topHBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout* leftTopVBoxLayout;

    QPixmap* m_pixLabelCurrency;
    QLabel* m_currencyLabelPicture;
    QLabel* m_nameOfCurrency;
    QLineEdit* m_edit1;
};

#endif // TOPAREACLASS_H

#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLineEdit>


class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
private slots:

private:
    QWidget* topArea;
    QWidget* leftTopArea;

    QHBoxLayout* topHBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout* leftTopVBoxLayout;

    QPixmap* m_pixLabelCurrency;
    QLabel* m_currencyLabelPicture;
    QLabel* m_nameOfCurrency;
    QLineEdit* m_edit1;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H


cpp:
#include "widget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}


#include "topareaclass.h"

topAreaClass::topAreaClass(const QString& Label,const QString& path, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
{
    //topArea
    topArea = new QWidget(this);
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    setFixedSize(500, 70);
    setStyleSheet("background: grey;");

    //leftTopArea
    leftTopArea = new QWidget(topArea);
    leftTopArea->setFixedSize(70, 70);
    leftTopArea->setStyleSheet("background: grey;");
    leftTopVBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout(leftTopArea);
    leftTopVBoxLayout->setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5);

    //Flag
    m_pixLabelCurrency = new QPixmap(path);
    m_currencyLabelPicture = new QLabel();
    m_currencyLabelPicture->setPixmap(m_pixLabelCurrency->scaled(60,30, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    m_currencyLabelPicture->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    //Usd
    m_nameOfCurrency = new QLabel(Label);
    m_nameOfCurrency->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);


    leftTopVBoxLayout->addWidget(m_currencyLabelPicture);
    leftTopVBoxLayout->addWidget(m_nameOfCurrency);

    //edit1 (topRight)
    m_edit1 = new QLineEdit("100000");
    m_edit1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    m_edit1->setStyleSheet("border: none;"
                           "font-size: 35px;"
                           "margin-right: 10px;");
    m_edit1->setFixedHeight(70);

    //QHBoxLayout

    topHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    topHBoxLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

    topHBoxLayout->addWidget(leftTopArea);
    topHBoxLayout->addStretch();
    topHBoxLayout->addWidget(m_edit1);
}

#include "widget.h"
#include "topareaclass.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(500,700);
    setStyleSheet("background: black;");
    setWindowTitle("Currency Convertor");

    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    topAreaClass* top1 = new topAreaClass("USD", ":/new/prefix1/build/usa.png");
    topAreaClass* top2 = new topAreaClass("UAH", ":/new/prefix1/build/uah.png");

    mainLayout->addWidget(top1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(top2);
    mainLayout->addStretch();
}

Widget::~Widget() {}


How can I fix it, so there isn't any space around widgets?

This is too much code for me to read, please read [mre]. But as a guess, based on your image, those are probably the layout margins and spacing.

Does this answer your question? Removing extra spacing around QWidget

See also: How to remove Qt widget (with layout) space

Nope, I've already tried it, and "contents margin" and "spacing" didn't work out. However, all code you should to read is in topareaclass.cpp

Do you have any others guesses?

Use @ in comments to ping users you address, if I haven't stumbled on your question again, I wouldn't have read your comments.

Re: "Do you have any others guesses?". No, my guess is still contentMargins. You probably have not used it on the correct layouts, for example: mainLayout in Widget's ctor.

"all code you should to read is in topareaclass.cpp". I wouldn't know, because it's hard to understand the structure of this UI. That is why a [mre] is required in this case, we should see the simplest representation of the problem, preferably just main.cpp (example), so we can copy-paste it into our IDE, and test directly, with little to no modification.

@A.R.M yeah, I completely forgot about mainLayout. And spacing in the middle of widgets caused by "topHVBoxLayout->addStretch()", don't know why, so thaks.

I'm glad that helped, and good luck with the rest. Please consider accepting the duplicate flag, as it helps future readers find more information.

@OleksiyRubakha You should also avoid setting generic QSS properties for parent/container widgets, as they propagate to children in unexpected ways; selector types should always be preferred instead. Also, the black background between those widgets is caused by the default autoFillBackground state, which is false for the basic QWidget.
